# incrementing inside a php function

Tags: php

I was wondering if you can help me with my php function

I have created a quiz which uses radio buttons and a submit button. I want the function to check if a specific radio button is selected and if so add 1 onto the user score. however nothing is being added the function for this is

```
    function Score()
{
    if(isset($_POST['correctAnswer'] ))

    {

        $answer=$_POST['correctAnswer'];
        $_SESSION['score']=$userScore+1;

    }

    else
    {
     $_SESSION['score']=$_SESSION['score'];

     }




}
```

and the form in which it is submitted is

```
echo '<strong>'."$theQuestion".'</strong><br>';
   ?> <form name="correctAnswer" form method="post" action="quiz.php" onSubmit="Score()"> 
  <?php
   echo "$theAnswer1";?> <input type="radio" id="correct_answer" name="correctAnswer">
  <?php
   echo "<br>$theAnswer2"; ?> <input type="radio" id="wrong_answer1" name="wrongAnswer1"> 
   <?php
   echo "<br>$theAnswer3"; ?> <input type="radio" id="wrong_answer2" name="wrongAnswer2"> 
   <?php
   echo "<br>$theAnswer4"; ?> <input type="radio" id="wrong_answer3" name="wrongAnswer3"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="score" value="userScore">
   <br><input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
   </form>
```

Hope you can help

Comment: And what is `$userScore`?

Comment: `$_SESSION['score']=$_SESSION['score']` does exactly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the counter as an argument of the function like this

```
 function Score($userScore){
    //Do the rest
 }
```

Comment: I tried doing that and yet it is still printing as 0 at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the $_SESSION['score'] is undefined

```
function Score() {

if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}
if (isset($_POST['correctAnswer'])) {

    $_SESSION['score']++;
}
```

}